# In Azure Devops how to I grant a single individual permissions to a 1 repo only, instead of all repos within the project?

Tags: azure-devops

I have an azure project with 5+ repositories. I understand how to add the individual to access all repos within the project. (Add them to Project Settings > Team)
However, is it possible to easily restrict access such that an individual can only commit to 1 single repo?

I was able to accomplish this 2 years back in GitHub and just looking for a comparable permissions separation. Any help is appreciated. Ill post my answer here if I am able to discover this. Still sort of struggling to figure this out after having spent some time on trying to discover this separation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Agree with @Daniel , you can set a single individual permission to a one repo by clicking Project Settings -> Repositories. Then you can set the permission to your expected repo or branch like below. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJdgD.png

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer could help you achieve grant a single individual permissions to a 1 repo? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave commend here :-)

Comment: @joey Did you tried out below solution? any good news?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT, thank you so much for the answer. Im sure its a good 1. Please give me a bit to test this out. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

From the repositories dropdown, choose "Manage Repositories". Or click on the project settings link at the bottom of the left nav, then choose "Repositories".

You can set security there.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I just got around to reading this. So can you be a little more specific about how to add a single individual?